# Location service going to "Inactive" state in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

Even my app is register for Location updates in background.

In my code:

```
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 2500;
```

And I not moved anywhere. So after exactly 15 minutes in console log I got this message **"Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'"** . From this point onwards my app is not running in background.

**It's happening in iPhone 5 only.**

@updated

Here is my code

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager setPurpose:@"Enable Location service for \"My App\" to track your"];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;

/* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
 * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 2500;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was your app in the background when location service become inactive?

If you don't want to pause location update in background than you need to set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically flag,

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) {
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
}
```

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Okay, here I have used self.locationManager, you need to use your CLLocationManager object.

Comment: Yes, I receievd "Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'" when   app in background. I will try this code.

Comment: But one thing, same code is worked for iPhone 4 with iOS 6 above. In iPhone 4 it's not stopping to receive location updates.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 6 Apple has added `@property(assign, nonatomic) BOOL pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `CLLocationManager`. Default value is `YES`. Change value of this property to `NO` and the location tracking will not stop in the background.