# CLLocation manager does not update locations if startUpdatingLocation is called when App is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager, background-process

I am using `CLLocationManager` in my app and `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` property is set to YES to save battery.When locations are paused and then I try to restart location updates after specified time interval using `startUpdatingLocation` method it starts and give 7 to 10 location updates.After that I dont get any further location updates.I call below method to restart updates.

PS:I have already enabled location Background mode in capabilities.

```
[_locManager startUpdatingLocation];
                if ([_locManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)])
                {
                    _locManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates =YES;
                }
```

Comment: @kb920 please read my question again.I am already setting this property to YES.

Comment: you are using `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{

}` delegate Method right?

Comment: @Vvk yes didUpdateLocations is being used.

Comment: try With Both Method one by one `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    
}`

Comment: The only fix I know (which I found from the duplicate) is to call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in the foreground.  If you do this then it seems you can call `startUpdatingLocations in the background and get updates indefinitely

Comment: @Paulw11 I cant force user to bring the app in foreground.Also I want to pause locations if user is not moving significantly to save battery life

Comment: Believe me, I have tried everything. You don't need to bring the app to the foreground, you just leave significant location monitoring on from the moment your app launches. Then you can start/stop location updates in the background and it will all work.  significant location monitoring doesn't use much battery.  My test app doesn't even show up in the list of apps using battery in device settings after days of running with just significant location monitoring

Answer (score 1):

Go to project build setting, Under target selected select capabilities - Turn on background mode - check the box location updates.

This can solve your problem i think.

Comment: That property is already.My code does not work once location updates are paused by OS due to pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property.

Comment: When app comes in foreground then is it updating ?

Comment: Yes then it updates.

Comment: i think that if you set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to yes then it is not allow background execution because of battery saving scenario.

Comment: But it gives 7 to 10 location on starting but after that it doesnt give locations

Comment: yes it's happens. app take little time to get notification that it's enter in background. you can check it for audio also. if your app plays audio or music and you press home button then your audio pause after 2 or 3 seconds like this location is also take time.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187700/startupdatelocations-in-background-didupdatingtolocation-only-called-10-20-time?lq=1

Comment: I cant rely on significant locations as I need complete accuracy on the data.